# Oracle ADF Application and OpenAM

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g, openam

Using OpenAM i am trying to protect an ADF application, i have installed the weblogic policy agent as documented.

i get prompted to login with the OpenAM screens however once logged in and redirected back to the application i get the following error

Error 403 -- Forbidden
The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

Is there any logs or anything i can look at to find the exact reasoning?

the only thing i can think of is its something to do with the ADF security.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Agent is running in 'ALL' mode, which means it's also enforcing authorizations for URL (urlPolicy). So you have to create URL policies as well.

However URL policies often do not make sense for Web Apps, so you could change the agent to run in 'SSO_ONLY' or 'J2EE' mode.

BTW the agent debug log (log level set to 'message' in agent profile) will tell you why it's denying access.